# How to open IntelliJ, PhpStorm in a method from an debug external link using file API localhost:63342/api/file/FILENAME:LINE

Tags: php, debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm, stack-trace

I'm improving a PHP function to debug by printing var contents stack trace, and other useful informations to help debugging. For every file:line, I put a URL to open it directly in PhpStorm, using it's file API:

```
http://localhost:63342/api/file/FILENAME:LINE
```

it's very useful because I don't have to hit <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> (same shortcuts as Sublime Text) to find file and then <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> to go to that line. I just click in the stacktrace link and my PhpStorm open the file right on the line.

It's so useful, that I added links in my Firefox bookmarks. The problem is: when you modify files, line numbers change.

**My first question is:** how to make PhpStorm open right on a method instead a line number

**Second question:** how to make it work in Mac OS (for me, it runs OK on Windows but not in Mac OS).

PhpStorm version in Windows: 2016.3.2
PhpStorm version in Mac OS: 2016.? (not sure, my macbook is in my home right now)

Comment: 1) Please check comments and stuff in this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879 2) Navigate to method from outside -- not sure; But internally -- easy: `Navigate | Class...` supports methods -- e.g. `someFile#method`